# TS not hint about allowed value, but work correctly

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I have two interfaces, a function overload. I want to return `string[]` if passed `First` and return `number[]` if passed `Second` and return `<T>` is not passed value. Code below works fine, but my intellisense not hint about allowed types. (it only if i added  overload)

[image]

Code

```html
type First = { type: 'first'; data: string };
type Second = { type: 'second'; data: number };

function func<T>(): Array<T>;
function func(value: First): Array<string>;
function func(value: Second): Array<number>;

function func(value?: First | Second) {
    if (value === undefined) return [];
    if (typeof value === 'number') return ['qwe'];
    return [1, 2, 3];
}

const a = func({ type: 'second', data: 123 });
const b = func({ type: 'first', data: "qwe" });

func({ data: 2, type: ''}) // here i can use only 'Second', but ts still hint only for 'First'
```

[TSPlay](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=17&pc=27#code/C4TwDgpgBAYglgJwM7CgXigbyqSAuKAcgDNEVCBuKAEwENhaCUE4A7AcygF8KAoXaAGUIAYwD2rauiw5wEAoSSiJ1SjXqMorAK4BbAEYQE3Pr2LbWI4HAlRzlgDwAVAHwAKAJQEAgggS0QZxc%20eysbVjsLETcAN1oAG215WDJgLyhff0DmNnZgsyjrW1DYhKSCYXFJdMyAhx0DI3yCyyKIkrjEiAB%20AnhkVAAfKEqVDyxeAEg4YihSrvQ0DAtqCFJWCGpxhAhgbQQIgG0AXT5p2bcBMVnOpMWMQgbDBEJt3f2jwgBHAHcIQlOUx2ewOUEOAEYADRQABM0IAzICuLxeFUUFBaNIStgBAolFVVNC6AwCOCYfDuB4%20GjUPosVE3Di5ApSANCESNAQAES-CBcymmbHqEmw6G4oiELgeIA)

Comment: Sadly, typescript autocompletion isn't perfect.

Comment: @AlexWayne yeah, may be I find solution

Answer (score 0):

[@Micah Zoltu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/879046/micah-zoltu) wrote me, that:

> Overloads tend to have problems.
> Even with a generic though, you still don't quite get the autocomplete you want unfortunately.

And I decide to fix it, just add new function with suffix 'T'. It can work as expected but need to use other function.

```html
type First = { type: 'first'; data: string };
type Second = { type: 'second'; data: number };

function func(value: First): Array<string>;
function func(value?: Second): Array<number>;

function func(value?: First | Second) {
    if (value === undefined) return [];
    if (typeof value === 'number') return ['qwe'];
    return [1, 2, 3];
}

function funcT<T = any>(): Array<T> {
    return func() as any;
}

const a = func({ type: 'second', data: 123 }); // number[]
const b = func({ type: 'first', data: "qwe" }); // string[]
const c = funcT(); // any[]
const d = funcT<boolean>(); // boolean[]
```

[TSPlay](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=20&pc=41#code/C4TwDgpgBAYglgJwM7CgXigbyqSAuKAcgDNEVCBuKAEwENhaCUE4A7AcygF8KAoXaAGUIAYwD2rauiw5wEAoSSiJ1SjXqMorAK4BbAEYQE3Pr2LbWI4HAlRzlgBQA3WgBtt82GWABKAgEEEBFoQAB5mNnYAPj57KxtWOwsRZzcPAH4CYXFJPyhA4LCdAyMY3jNk61s41PcITK9kVAAfKGyVHyxeAEg4Yihaj3Q0DAtqCFJWCGpOhAhgbQREgG0AXT5e-ocBMX6XOuGMQmLDBEJZ%20cWVwgBHAHcIQnWeuYWlqGWARgAaKAAmX4AZmeXHKcSqiTiABVQlDpLRWCAog48gUQrCol1uq8rklHJ1aEgoAiQHxQbwcihidIatgBAolDlVL86AwCJ8-oDuD4qAB6XlaPSnNYUiRU-Q05IOOlyBSkJqEFkaAgAInuEBV3L5AoiHBFlNQIkllihKO1xMR%20rFqCkGGhoX0YjErggCORPKg-KgjudrtYayAA)